# REGEX - Pattern Needed to exclude

Tags: regex

I have a URL rewrite in IIS that's triggering on 3 URL's but I only want it to trigger on two URL's

```
http://www.example.com/resources/myresource
http://www.example.com/resources/myresource/
http://www.example.com/resources/myresourceKB
```

The first two urls' I want it trigger on but not the third one.

I was using `resoucres/myresource` as my regex pattern, but then I noticed the third URL got included in it.

How can I make the regex capture the first 2 url's but not the third?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use negative look ahead `(?!)`:

```
http://www.example.com/resources/myresource(?!KB)
```